# cakePHP hasMany not joining the SQL query

Tags: cakephp, model, controller

I am unable to do a simple condition for my paginator. I have a Survey and Campaign models. Campaigns hasMany Surveys setup in the Campaign model.

I want to select a survey and the paginator should display the campaign is linked to, but I keep getting a Unknown column Survey.id - On inspection I see that Survey is not joined to the Campaign model, only in the WHERE clause. I also found out that hasMany does not join the tables to the query.

How else can I go about doing the above?

Comment: If Campaigns hasMany Surveys, Surveys have one Campaign, isn't it ? So if you select one specific Survey, it will be linked to only one Campaign ?
Then why would you need pagination here ? There is probably something I don't understand. That said, in some cases filtering on `Model1.model2_id` instead of `Model2.id` can help.

Comment: What I have is a page with campaigns (the pagination is for this page). I want a dropdown where the user can select a survey, and the result would then return the 1 campaign linked to that one). So the paging page would only have 1 result. It's just a quick way to get to the campaign (if you know what the survey is but not the campaign it's linked in)

Comment: It's not the most elegant of solutions, but you can try manually added the relation in the `joins` key. Although, I recently found this (which I was meaning to make) which makes it much simpler (less code) [link](http://cfc.kizzx2.com/index.php/restoring-elegance-to-cakephp-doing-multiple-joins-the-right-way/)

Comment: Although I just noticed that your relations may be setup wrong. If its Campaign hasMany Survey, then Survey should have campaign_id. So I don't know why its looking for Survey.id. In your database do you have Survey.campaign_id or Campaign.survey_id ?

Comment: I have Survey.campaign_id - Remember that campaigns does not have 1 survey, but multiple ones, so it wont have a survey_id, and this is where the problem is coming in. in sql it would have been a simple "SELECT campaign.id FROM campaign, survey WHERE survey.id=VALUE"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find an answer to this. It appears that hasMany does not automatically get added to a query. I have had recommendations that using the containable feature in cake may help.